# Inflector not respecting custom rules

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP 3.7.

I have added, at the bottom of `config/bootstrap.php`:

`Inflector::rules('irregular', ['thesis' => 'theses']);`

and actually, I've tried

`Inflector::rules('irregular', ['theses' => 'thesis']);`

just in case I had it backwards.

And in a cell I am trying to use:

```
    use Cake\Utility\Inflector;

    $singular_and_plural = [Inflector::singularize($base_name), $base_name];
```

The result for singularizing the word "thesis" is "thesiss".

Can anyone point out what's wrong, here?

Comment: It seems to work properly for me without requiring a special rule within a Shell. Probably doesn't help, sorry. `Array
(
    [0] => thesis
    [1] => theses
)`

Answer (score 1):

The first form is the correct one, the key is the singular value, and the value the plural value.

That being said, what you're showing here is incorrect/problematic usage of `Inflector::singularize()`, as you're passing a value to it that already is singular, doing that often gives you unexpected/wrong results. You could open an issue ticket in such cases, sometimes this can be fixed in the core, but often times it's simply not possible as it would conflict with existing, required rules.

It should also be noted that CakePHP can handle `thesis`/`theses` out of the box already, it has singular/plural rules that match that. Make sure that you are passing in the expected values, and that you don't have additional custom rules that may interfer with what you're trying to inflect.